# Best way to store followed users

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema

I know the title isn't so describing but it's really hard to find something generic to describe my situation. If someone wants to edit, feel free...

So, I have a postgres database, with a `users` table. I would like to store the users followed by one user, and I really don't see how I could do this. I would like to do like `SELECT followed_users FROM users WHERE username='username'` and this would return me every usernames, or id, or whatever of each followed users. But I don't see any **clean** way to do this.

Maybe an example would be more describing: `user1` is following `user2` and `user3`.
**How to store who `user1` is following?**

**EDIT:** I don't know how many users the user will follow.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create a new table called something like `user_follows` with columns like `user_id1 | user_id2` or `follower_id | follows_id` if you want more description, or if you think that you might have more relationships besides `follows` then make a table like `relationships` with `user_id1 | user_id2 | relationship` where `relationships.relationship` might have values like `follows, student of, sister of` etc...

Comment: I forgot to mention: I don't know how many users the user will follow, so I don't know if this would be a nice solution, or maybe I haven't understood the answer. Sorry if I don't understand, it's hard for me to visualize this

Comment: @Jhun Based on your description, JNevill's solution (in the comments) is going to be your best option. To expand upon it, to get the users that a user follows, you'd do something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id2 FROM user_follows WHERE user_id1='4')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, since it got wordy:

Create a new table called something like `user_follows` with columns like

```
user_id1 | user_id2
```

or

```
follower_id | follows_id
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT t1.username as follower_username, t3.username as following_usernae
FROM users t1
    INNER JOIN user_follows t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.follower_id
    INNER JOIN users t3 ON t2.following_id = t3.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id = <your user>
```

In the end, think of your tables as "Objects". Then when you are presented with a problem like "How do I add users that are following other users" you can determine if this relationship is a new object, or an attribute of an existing object. Since a user might follow more than one other user than the relationship is not a good attribute for "Users", so it gets its own table `user_follows`.

Since `user_follows` is just one type of relationship that two users may have to one another, it might make sense to increase the scope of that object to `relationships` and store the relationship type as an attribute of the table:

```
user_id1 | user_id2 | relationship_type
```

where `relationships.relationship_type` might have values like `follows, student of, sister` of etc...

So the new query would be something like:

```
SELECT t1.username as follower_username, t3.username as following_username
FROM users t1
    INNER JOIN relationships t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id1
    INNER JOIN users t3 ON t2.user_id2 = t3.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id = <your user> AND t2.relationship_type = 'Follows';
```

Comment: I'll stick to this design. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd add another table, let's call it `following` for argument's sake, which saves pairs of users and users they are following:

```
CREATE TABLE following (
    user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id), 
    following_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, following_id)
)
```

Then you could query all the user's a specific user is following by joining with the `users` table (twice). E.g., to get the names of all the users that I (username "mureinik") am following:

```
SELECT fu.username
FROM   following f
JOIN   users u ON f.user_id = u.id
JOIN   users fu ON f.user_id = fu.id
WHERE  u.username = 'mureinik'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll stick to this, as it's the same design as @JNevill's